# Is replicating data from mysql to sqlite data sync?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, synchronization

I am creating an Andriod app that allow users to register and save cards form their account...the remote db is MySQL and the cards saved online can be saved to local SQLite db as well by clicking a button(not sure whether to name it 'Sync' or not). If cards added or removed online...that can also be replicated on local SQLite clicking that button. So, would it be correct to call it data sync?

Comment: Once date is changed online for that card you can send a notification to device this data changed based on that device will sync data from server and get the date based on last sync time

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Sunil. So, it can be called as data sync?

Comment: Yes it's data sync from server